# How to publish a react app on GitHub pages within an existing repository?

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I have a website published on GitHub pages. How to publish a React JS app within a folder of the repository of my website?

Answer (score 0):

You can link the JS file to the HTML file using the `<script>` tag.